# Averages of cells with same ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I want to calculate averages of several cells in column W. The condition is that they have to have the same ID-number in column B. For instance I want the average of all cells in column W that have ID 54, 62, 77 and 80.

Comment: Having a problem with the [AVERAGEIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-ff3c70f9-5afe-4d3e-87d4-717187f98c20)?

Comment: Please, add some graphical representation to explain, what you mean. What cells will be calculate etc.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe (same layout as @Gary's Student's answer):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(W:W,B:B,{54,62,77,80}))/SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(B:B,{54,62,77,80}))
```

though possibly with `,`s replaced by `;`s.

@Jeeped has kindly pointed out that the above is more elaborate than necessary, as the SUMPRODUCT is overkill where SUM is sufficient (i.e. it accepts array input):

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(W:W,B:B,{54,62,77,80}))/SUM(COUNTIFS(B:B,{54,62,77,80}))
```

Image (courtesy @Jeeped also!):

[image: SO34086582 example]

Based on @Gary's Student's answer's data, the result is `54.15`.

Comment: Those don't actually have to be [SUMPRODUCT functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff). The [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) and [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) spit back arrays that can be collected by a simple [SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57), See [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJOiL.png).

Answer (score 0):

With data like:

[image]

use formulas like:

```
=AVERAGEIF(B1:B20,62,W1:W20)
```

one formula for each *ID*